# Auto Update application

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a solution (better if Open Source) to allow me add Auto Update functionality to my Windows applications. I should be able to detect new versions and automatically download the new version from a server, then uninstall the old version and install the new one.

Thanks in advance,
Leonardo.

Comment: Good luck with this crusade. Software vendors do not follow a standard for software updates, so each process will be different. The larger your list of software vendors, the bigger the headache. Seems to be an area where *nix distros have a serious advantage over Windows.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a solution to add to my software only. I created a basic solution, but there are many things to take into account, like "is the application running?, has the user rights to write in this directory?", and I preffer to be focused in improving my software instead of creating the auto update feature.

Answer (score 4):

The only library I know of for Windows is WinSparke (http://winsparkle.org/), which is based off the popular Sparkle framework on the Mac (http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/).

But then again, I do not dabble in Windows all too much anymore. There might be better alternatives now, but I'd personally try WinSparkle.

Answer (score 0):

this is not applicable in all situations, but there are also some package managers for Windows you can use. I'd of course recommend [Npackd](http://code.google.com/p/windows-package-manager/) :-)